# GCS Private Bucket but objects or folder private

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

Using a GCS bucket to store the files like invoice but the issue I am facing is access issue on those files (objects) since my bucket is private.

Is there any way I can acccess the objects with keeping my bucket as private. Only read access to the public users something.

Comment: Do you want to allow read access to all document and to keep for you only the create/delete permissions?

Comment: Yes @guillaumeblaquiere

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make your bucket public! Grant the special user "allUsers", the role "Object viewer". Like that, any unauthenticated user will be able to view and download the file.

The role object admin (that allows to read, write and delete the object) MUST not be granted on allUsers, but only to admin, like you.